# Firebase simple chat with Polymer elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have created the [Firebase basic chat app](https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#gettingstarted) and it works great. I wanted to use Polymer paper-input but I can't get to add an id on the paper-input element.

**The old way:**

```
<input type='text' id='nameInput' placeholder='Name'>
```

**Polymer:**

```
<paper-input id="fullName" label="full name"></paper-input> //I have added the id
```

**The script:**

```
var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://demo.firebaseio-demo.com/');
       $('#textInput').keypress(function (e) {
         if (e.keyCode == 13) {
           // get id from paper-input
           var name = $('#fullName').val();
           var text = $('#textInput').val();
            // preventing empty data entry
            if (name !== "") {
              myDataRef.push({name: name, text: text});
              $('#textInput').val('');
              alert('Your text has been sent');

            }
         }
       });
```

**This also does not work:**

```
 var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://demo.firebaseio-demo.com/');
   $('#textInput').find('input').keypress(function (e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 13) {
       var name = $('#fullName').find('input').val();
       var text = $('#textInput').find('input').val();
        // preventing empty data entry
        if (name !== "") {
          myDataRef.push({name: name, text: text});
          $('#textInput').find('input').val('');
          alert('You message has been sent');
        }
     }
   });
```

Let's disregard the text input field for this example. How to add an id on polymer input elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add an id on the `<input>` element itself inside the polymer element, adding it to the `<paper-input>` should work fine as well and should also work with your code. You can call .val() on the jquery version of the paper-element and that should work, calling .value on the HTML element (non-jquery) also works.

If you really do need to get the input element inside the paper-input element, simply use `$('#fullName').find('input')` to get it.

What in your code doesn't work? As far as i know this should work fine.

Comment: When I use `paper-input` Im not getting .push() to store in the database. If I use the standard html input, all works. Adding `$('#fullName').find('input')` does not work either. I'll update the question to what does not work

Comment: Are you sure that you have imported the polymer elements and they work fine? Maybe try adding some console.log()'s to log the name and text variables so you can see what kind of value you are getting (maybe text is not empty, or maybe you are just getting undefined back instead of any string).

Comment: Sorry about that. I was typing `$('#fullName'),find('input')` See the comma before find? DWL. Thanks. My mistake